# Find max value from last 50 nodes from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to find max value from only last 50 nodes. I used to orderByChild and limitToLast methods but it finds max from all nodes, not only from last 50.
Here my db:
[image]

And my code:

```
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = database.getReference("sensor");

 Query query = reference.orderByChild("hum").limitToLast(50);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                humTemp = myDataSnapshot.child("hum").getValue().toString();
                humMax.setText(humTemp);
                }
            }
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

            }

        });
```

So, as you see i try to find max value of hum variable from last 50 nodes.
P.S. New nodes are constantly appearing in the database, so the maximum value should change for every 50 values in realtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the maximum of the 50 most recent nodes, you're trying to order by two properties:

- humidity
- the time of the node (or its key)

Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property.

In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase. But I don't think that's possible for you.

The best I can think of is to just listen for the last 50 nodes, and then re-ordering them on humidity in the client.